# Fill a path with multiple colors

Tags: skiasharp

How can I fill a path with SkiaSharp with multiple colors? So each segment of the path should have another colors? This image is a path where the colors are representing the elevation.
[image: Path with colors depending on elevation]

Comment: It's not supported in Skia out of the box. You might want to chop the path into short straight line segments and draw each with an interpolated color you need.